# How do I add time to another Time instance in Java

Tags: java, datetime, calendar

I have the following requirements:

1) I need to calculate the current UTC time in milliseconds.

2) I have to add time in seconds to (1) and insert the sum into sqlite db as an integer.

(3) I need to read (2) from the database and display the value in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format.

I tried multiple options

```
static LocalDateTime millisecondsToDateTime(long milliseconds) {
    return Instant.ofEpochMilli(milliseconds).atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toLocalDateTime();
}
```

My unit test

```
@Test
  public void testOne() throws Exception {
    LocalDateTime actual = millisecondsToDateTime(3600);
    LocalDateTime expected = LocalDateTime.of(1970, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0);
    Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
  }
```

This unit test fails for me.

I have tried multiple techniques such as the one given below. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am using Java 8, so I can use the developed JDK APIs.

Comment: So, As per provided test, are you facing problem only in the 3 step? ie converting timestamp into YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS ?

Comment: @AnilPurohit Actually in all scenarios..

Comment: It is not okay to store UTC-time as type `LocalDateTime`. Simply use the class `Instant` only where you can also add seconds to. If you read the instant from DB then you can format it using any timezone.

Comment: How would you suggest I do it. I am open to using any library or native Java 8 APIs.

Comment: I suspect your bug is a confusion between seconds and milliseconds. 3600 looks like seconds (1 hour), but your method uses the number as milliseconds (3.6 seconds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the below code, you can change it as per your requirements.

```
        // Create an instant object from the timestamp
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(3600);
        instant.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);

        //Add X number of days to instant
        instant.plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);


        // Create a date formatter
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS");
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

        // Create the date from instant & format it from date formatter
        Date date = Date.from(instant);
        String formattedDate = formatter.format(date);
        System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Comment: How do I get the current time in milliseconds at UTC? Will System.currentMillis.. work?

Comment: @Kartik, yes it will.

Comment: @AnilPurohit, there’s no need to bring in the outdated classes `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. No matter if you use `SimpleDateFormat` or the modern `DateTimeFormatter`, please watch the case of your format pattern string. You probably want `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

Comment: `instant.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);` is a no-operation. It returns a `ZonedDateTime`, but if you don’t use that `ZonedDateTime` object for anything, you might as well leave out the statement. Similarly for `instant.plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);` (returns an `Instant` that you ignore).

Comment: But I need to get the instant at UTC time that I need to convert to java.sql.TimeStamp